# Heroku at Home?

Tags: heroku

[Heroku buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks) (along with [mason](https://github.com/ddollar/mason)) let me create slugs from my applications on my own computer, is there a way (VirtualBox? Vagrant?) to run slugs on my own box so I could create something like a mini-heroku?

**EDIT**

The more I read about mason, the more it seems like the solution to this. However the documentation is thin, and I run into the error `Malformed version number string sh` when I try to build, or `no such file to load -- foreman/engine (LoadError)` if I try to run the build on the lucid64 virtual machine. Any help with these issues would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a little difficulty getting it working at the moment, but if you've come across this with the same question, take a look at @peterkeen's [dokuen](https://github.com/peterkeen/dokuen) it manages a locl heroku-type environment!